# Download PDF from google.script.run in web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, data-uri

What I'm trying to achieve is to download sheet as .PDF file from google script web app, but I have a problem: output file has (probably) wrong encoding (UTF-8 also doesn't work).

Example:

Good file:
downloaded from link with "export?exportFormat=pdf..."

```
%PDF-1.4
% âăĎÓ
4
0
obj
<<
/Type
/Catalog
/Names
<<
/JavaScript
3

...
```

Corrupted file:

```
%PDF-1.4
% ????
4
0
obj
<<
/Type
/Catalog
/Names
<<
/JavaScript
3

...
```

Did anyone experienced similar problem? How can I solve it? Thank you in advance.

Google script:

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate();
}

function test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var url = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&gid=' + 
                 sheet.getSheetId();

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob();

  var charset = 'ISO-8859-1';
  var str = blob.getDataAsString(charset);

  return Utilities.base64Encode(str);
}
```

HTML JavaScript (index.html):

```
...

function downloadURI(uri, name) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.download = name;
  link.href = uri;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((data) => {

  var uri = 'data:application/pdf;charset=ISO-8859-1;base64,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
  downloadURI(uri, 'test.pdf');

}).withFailureHandler((err) => {
  console.log(err);
}).test();
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kCcxRbucbvKRSCMC4fNj9NJbjTJHTTBFXP7TLGmDNtQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the blob of `var blob = response.getBlob()` is created as a PDF file using `DriveApp.createFile(blob)`, if you can see the PDF completely, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
var blob = response.getBlob();
var charset = 'ISO-8859-1';
var str = blob.getDataAsString(charset);
return Utilities.base64Encode(str);
```

#### To :

```
var blob = response.getBlob();
return Utilities.base64Encode(blob.getBytes());
```

#### Reference :

- [Utilities.base64Encode()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#base64Encode(Byte))

If this was not the direct solution for your issue, I'm sorry.